# How to convert wchar_t to V8 String?

Tags: c++, node.js

I want to return a wchar_t array in a node addon. How can I convert the wchar_t array so that the V8 engine accepts it?

```cpp
// This is the normal way i return an string back to javascript
args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "MY_TEXT", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked());

// This is my code where i want to return the "textBuffer" back to Javascript.

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    ...

    const int bufferSize = 1024;
    wchar_t textBuffer[bufferSize];
    int copied = SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);
    printf("Copied %d chars.\n", copied);
    printf("getting text:\n");
    //wprintf(L"%ls \n", textBuffer);

    // RETURN THE textBuffer as STRING HERE

    //args.GetReturnValue().Set( HERE );
    //args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "test", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked());

}
```

Comment: You'll need to find out the encoding of the string. To find the native wide encoding of the system, first step is to figure out what system you are targetting.

Comment: The code only works on Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code will convert a `wchar_t` string to a UTF-8 string.  Please note though that `std::codecvt` is deprecated as of C++17 (although there is no adequate replacement).

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

std::string ws_to_UTF8 (const wchar_t *ws)
{
    std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8 <wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes (ws);
}
```

You can then call `c_str ()` on the returned string to get a C-style UTF8 string to pass to `args.GetReturnValue().Set ()`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But i get strange characters out. https://i.imgur.com/tWToUsq.jpg

Comment: Is this a Unicode build?  Also, what do you get if you convert a string consisting entirely of ASCII characters?  And have you walked it through in the debugger to see what values you are getting in your strings?

Comment: When i print the textBuffer in Visual Studio i get the normal german text. With (wprintf(L"%ls \n", textBuffer);), when i use ws_to_UTF8 i become these strange characters. (In the Node.JS addon)

Comment: When i use "printf("%s \n", ws_to_UTF8(textBuffer).c_str());" in Visual Studio it prints the right string. When i do the same in the Node.JS addon it gives me stange characters.

Comment: And when i use codecvt_utf16 then the text looks like my text, but but it's still wrong. -> https://i.imgur.com/JD8zLXH.png (Right is the text in Visual Studio)

Comment: _When i use "printf("%s \n", ws_to_UTF8(textBuffer).c_str());" in Visual Studio it prints the right string. When i do the same in the Node.JS addon it gives me stange characters._  I'm afraid you have reached the limit of my expertise.  `ws_to_UTF8` is doing what it is designed to do (i.e. convert a Unicode string of `wchar_t`s to a UTF-8 string of `char`s, and your question implies that that is what Node.JS is expecting, but since I don't know Node.JS I don't know why it isn't happy, sorry.